# Mocking EF Core Database Context using Moq and xUnit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, moq

I want to know how to use Moq for mocking my EF Core's `DbContext` when I am using DI to provide my Database context to the controller as shown below:

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    private AppDbContext context;
    public RegisterController(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        context = appDbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Register register)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Add(register);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Read");
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
}
```

Here `AppDbContext` is my database context for the EF core.

I want to write test case for the `Create` action. I have tried the below code:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_Create_POST_ValidModelState()
{
    // Arrange
    var r = new Register()
    {
        Id = 4,
        Name = "Test Four",
        Age = 59
    };

    var mockRepo = new Mock<AppDbContext>();
    mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<Register>()))
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask)
        .Verifiable();
    var controller = new RegisterController(mockRepo.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.Create(r);

    // Assert
    var redirectToActionResult = Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
    Assert.Null(redirectToActionResult.ControllerName);
    Assert.Equal("Read", redirectToActionResult.ActionName);
    mockRepo.Verify();
}
```

The main problem here is that I cannot do:

```
var mockRepo = new Mock<AppDbContext>();
```

I want to follow this approach as I have already added in-memory database.

Note that I know there is a another way to test with repository pattern. Which can be done by changing the create action as:

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    private IRegisterRepository context;
    public RegisterController(IRegisterRepository appDbContext)
    { 
        context = appDbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Register register)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await context.CreateAsync(register);
            return RedirectToAction("Read");
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
}
```

Where the interface `IRegisterRepository` and `RegisterRepository.cs` codes are:

```
public interface IRegisterRepository
{     
    Task CreateAsync(Register register);
}

public class RegisterRepository : IRegisterRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext context;

    public RegisterRepository(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        context = dbContext;
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(Register register)
    {
        context.Register.Add(register);
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

and the startup.cs code which add it as a service is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDb"));
    services.AddScoped<IRegisterRepository, RegisterRepository>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

I do not want to follow this approach (the repository pattern). I want to fake database context directly because I want to directly do the insertion of the record in the create action as the controller is getting database context object in it's constructor.

So how to write fake database context using moq in this test methods here?

Comment: If you can't `new Mock<AppDbContext>()` and you dont want to abstract your `AppDbContext` out, then why not just spin up an actual `AppDbContext`?

Comment: Have you considered using the InMemoryDatabase package to test this?

Comment: @mxmissile how. Please write an answer so that I can understand.

Comment: @ShafiqJetha yes i am using in-memory database.

Comment: If you're already using the in memory database then you should just need to instantiate a new dB context with a builder that points to this database. Then seed the data and run your tests.

Comment: I think the point of using Moq and why we abstract things out (with interfaces) is missing here. OP maybe clarify your intentions here, there might be a better / easier way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't mock DbContext**, because tests with mocking dbContext will not provide good quality feedback for developer.

Mocked DbContext will verify only that some method are called, which will convert code maintenance (refactoring) into a nightmare.

Instead use In-Memory provider or Sqlite provider with "in-memory" feature.

[EF Core In-Memory Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

[Using SQLite to test an EF Core application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite#:%7E:text=Using%20SQLite%20in%2Dmemory%20databases,-Normally%2C%20SQLite%20creates&text=SQLite%20can%20also%20use%20databases,connection%20to%20it%20is%20closed)

Alternative approach is to test against actual database - such tests will provide more confidence that application works correctly in "production" environment.

Comment: But i want to use database context to be directly injected to the controller and the controller actions will then directly use database context to do CRUD operations. So in that case I want to write test methods. So how to do this with moq?

Comment: You don't need to use Moq, you can inject actual DbContext, but register it with in-Memory provider.

Comment: thank you. I understood that Moq cannot be used in this case. I have to directly use in-memory provider for doing testing as done here - https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Miscellaneous/Testing/ItemsWebApi/Tests/ItemsControllerTest.cs

Answer (score 3):

There are several really useful libraries which does support what you are looking for.
Here are two of my favourite ones:

#### EntityFrameworkCore3Mock

[Github repo](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock)

The only prerequisite is that you have to define your `DbSet` as `virtual`.

```cs
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

Then the mocking would be this easy:

```cs
var initialEntities = new[]
{
    new Entity { ... },
    new Entity { ... },
};

var dbContextMock = new DbContextMock<AppDbContext>(DummyOptions);
var usersDbSetMock = dbContextMock.CreateDbSetMock(x => x.Entities, initialEntities);
```

#### EntityFrameworkCore.Testing

[Github repo](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing)

The only difference here is how you initialize the table with data:

```cs
var initialEntities = new[]
{
    new Entity { ... },
    new Entity { ... },
};


var dbContextMock = Create.MockedDbContextFor<AppDbContext>();
dbContextMock.Set<Entity>().AddRange(initialEntities);
dbContextMock.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: is there a way to do with without using any of these libraries.

Comment: @yogihosting Why would you want to do that? You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Just use the tools that makes your life easier.